# Interacting with cPanel via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel

I used to use 000WebHost and found that they have a custom version of cPanel written via PHP which interacts with cPanel.

Could anyone explain how this works?

Thanks,

Connor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the cPanel / WHM [API.](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/SoftwareDevelopmentKit/WebHome)

Comment: Ah, OK. How does their custom site-builder integrate with cPanel then?

Comment: Try reading the cPanel API docs, AFAIK it enables you to control cPanel, like adding databases, accounts, view files, etc. cPanel is just the middle-man between the browser and the Linux OS. :)

Comment: The reason I'm confused is that cPanel is closed source. Read here --> [link](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1057634)

Comment: Yes, you are right - so is Facebook, but they have created an API for programmers to access and utilize their services. So has cPanel. :)

Comment: Ah, OK. Is cPanel written in Perl?

Comment: I think they used Perl for some of the more OS-specific actions, and use PHP to use those Perl scripts/programs. You are able to run Linux Shell commands with PHP as well. :)

Comment: How does it work when cPanel has .html files then, but it is dynamic?

Comment: Well, that depends. If ALL they use is HTML files, they probably set up their Apache Config to have PHP parse HTML files, too. If not, it could be they are not using any PHP code in those files whose extension is HTML, and if and if they do have any dynamic content in those files, they could be using AJAX

Comment: Because I go to my email page and it is `pop.html` but I can create email accounts and they show up. Does it perhaps rewrite the page?

Comment: I just tested it - it appears they're using an AJAX request on page-load to load those E-Mail addresses and display them to you.

Comment: From what url do the addresses come?

Comment: http://YOURDOMAIN.com:2082/cpsess5916040709/json-api/cpanel?cpanel_jsonapi_version=2&cpanel_jsonapi_func=listpopswithdisk&cpanel_jsonapi_module=Email&api2_paginate=1&api2_paginate_size=10&api2_paginate_start=1&api2_sort=1&api2_sort_column=user&api2_sort_method=alphabet&api2_sort_reverse=0&cache_fix=1341391079634

Comment: It returns JSON data, and using Javascript, they populate the table for you. There is a PHP script that generates the JSON data (atleast thats what it looks like).

Comment: Ah, OK. Thanks. While I'm here, is there any way of finding what a file extension is for a file on a website using `Mod_Rewrite`?

Comment: I don't think you can. I suggest getting Firebug for Firefox, its a great tool for sniffing HTTP requests, to see how stuff works, and for debugging your own stuff.

Comment: If you think my info helped you, feel free to accept the answer. :)